# CheckboxFor; LabelFor has 'for' empty

Tags: asp.net-mvc

the following wont work properly.

```
 <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<List<TINK.Models.FlatLBProductType>>" %>

<% for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++) {  %>
    <div class="editor-label">
        <%= Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model[i].PT_Bestelbaar) %>
        <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model[i].PT_Bestelbaar)%>
    </div>
<% } %>
```

This generates the following HTML

```
<div class="editor-label"> 
<input type="checkbox" value="true" name="[1].PT_Bestelbaar" data-val-required="The PT_Bestelbaar field is required." data-val="true" checked="checked"> 
<input type="hidden" value="false" name="[1].PT_Bestelbaar"> 
<label for="">PT_Bestelbaar</label> 
</div>
```

why is the `for` empty in the label? Or how can I make this work?

Comment: Because a label can't point to two input elements having same name

Answer (score 0):

I think your View has an IEnumerable model definition, like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyModel>
```

and so I hope this helps you:

```
<% foreach (var item in Model) {  %>
    <div class="editor-label">
        <%= Html.CheckBox(item.PT_Bestelbaar) %>
        <%= Html.Label(item.PT_Bestelbaar)%>
    </div>
<% } %>
```

if you want to mantain the for loop please post the model definition. Regards.

Comment: Except for model binding purposes, he'll want to keep the `for` loop.

Comment: indeed need it for model binding upon post.